# Azure pipeline foreach loop

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am having some problem to figure out the issue in this pipeline.

I have a GitHub repo which contains one folder named `dist`. This folder has inside multiple files and folder. Here is the structure of my git hub:

```
├── README.md
├── client_pipeline.yaml
├── client_template.yaml
└── dist
    ├── ReportPhishingOutlookAddIn.xml
    └── ReportPhishingOutlookAddInWeb
        ├── Content
        ├── Dialog.html
        ├── Functions
        ├── Images
        └── Scripts
```

What I want to do, is when I create a new folder in this repo my pipeline should trigger and upload the dist folder content inside this new folder and save it in azure storage.

So I decided to go with a azure pipeline template first to define the logic of the pipeline:

Client_template.yaml

```
parameters:
  storageaccount: ''
  client: []
steps:
  - ${{ each client in parameters.client }}:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Azure CLI'
      inputs:
        AzureSubscription: '<mysubscription>'
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |

         az storage blob upload-batch --source dist --destination '$web/${client}' --account-name ${{ parameters.storageaccount}} --output table --no-progress
```

And I created another pipeline to call this template.

client_pipeline.yaml

```
variables:
  - name: storageaccount
    value: <mystorageaccount>

steps:
  - template: client_template.yaml
    parameters:
      storageaccount: ${{ variables.storageaccount }}
      client: ["folder","folder1"]
```

The second pipeline I am using it to give me freedom to add as many clients as I want and the pipeline should just create them in an azure storage account.

When I run my pipeline, it builds everything without any problem, but when I go in my storage account I have 2 issues.

The first one is that the folder name is `${client}` and not the actual name of the name I specified in my array.

The second issue is that the upload, uploads only the main folder and none of the subfolders.

Any help guys please?

EDIT:
I solved the issue number 1, now I am able to create multiple folders.
But still it doesn't copy all the subfolders and file in folder inside dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reference to this thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5420#issuecomment-487169413,

```
az storage azcopy blob upload
-c containerName
--account-name accountName
-s directory/path
-d upload/path
```

If the sub folder is need to be uploaded, the flag `--recursive` can be added.

Therefore, you could have a recursive flag that when set will upload subdirectories. Including the `--recursive` flag with az storage blob upload-batch would upload subdirectories. An example could be `az storage blob upload-batch -d <container name> -s <path/to/directory> --recursive`. Not including the recursive flag would then only upload files of a particular directory.

**Update**>>
As Nayden has resolved this issue by using the upload batch. If the subfolder is empty, it get ignored and not copied. As soon as We put some files inside all the subfolder, the upload-batch made a recursive copy without any extra flag.

Posting here so other community members who get the same issues can find the answer quickly.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. So I solved both issues using the upload batch. One thing I realised is if the subfolder is empty, it get ignored and not copied. As soon as I put some files inside all the subfolder, the upload-batch made a recursive copy without any extra flag. Thank you very much for your help and time mate.

Comment: Gladly to hear that your issue is resolved by using the upload batch. I have updated the answer regarding to your reply and hope it will help others who get the same issue in the future. Thanks for your sharing.